# Send packet to a machine behind router

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, packet, denial-of-service

**Context**

I'm learning how the internet works, and I am trying to send a TCP packet from my VPS to my computer.

My VPS has a specific public IP address so I can easily send from my computer to my VPS. However, my computer doesn't have a specific public IP address, since it belongs to a private network, and all the other devices on this network have the same public IP address.

**Question**

Is there a way to directly send a packet to a machine from my VPS? A solution would be to port forward, but is there a way to do that without taking action on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot initiate a TCP session from a host on the public side of a NAT (technically NAPT) gateway to a host on the private side without a port forwarding rule in place on the NAT gateway.

Comment: ty for youre answer; this is kinda annoying... Are there other protocols that allow that ?

Comment: @XenonPower No, you can't address a packet to a private IP address and then send it across the public Internet. So you can only address it to the NAT gateway's public IP address, but without an existing connection or a port forwarding rule (or a DMZ / "bastion host" / "default host" setting), the NAT gateway won't have any way to tell who it is for. The Port Control Protocol allows clients to dynamically register desired port forwarding rules, if the NAT supports it and the administrator allows it. UPnP also has a way for clients to register desired port forwarding rules.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying that !